# Setting up php-casperjs with composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm having trouble setting up php-casperjs for my project. I've never used composer before, so I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong.

I got xampp installed on Windows with php version 5.6.12

Here are the steps I completed so far.

1. Downloaded and installed composer. It launches successfully from the command prompt.
2. Downloaded php-casperjs and extracted **composer.json** and **src/Casper.php** into my project folder C:\xampp\htdocs\test
3. Navigated to the project folder in the command prompt and ran ***composer install*** command which installed 22 packages
4. Then I ran ***composer require phpcasperjs/phpcasperjs*** command and here I ran into problems. I get the following error message

> ```
> Using version ^1.2 for phpcasperjs/phpcasperjs
> ./composer.json has been updated
> Loading composer repositories with package information
> Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
> - The requested package phpcasperjs/phpcasperjs No version set (parsed as 1.0.0) is satisfiable by phpcasperjs/phpcasperjs[No version
> set (parsed as 1.0.0)] but these conflict with your requirements or
> minimum-stability.
>
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original
> content.
> ```

When I run the following php code

```
use Browser\Casper;
$casper = new Casper();
```

I get Fatal error: Class 'Browser\Casper' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 3

Comment: open up your composer.json and set the version for phpcasperjs/phpcasperjs. Find out the stable version and put into this file composer.json and then run composer install command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step1:** Go to you project directory and create a file "**composer.json**"
codes for composer.json
`{
    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "1.0.*"
    }
}`

**Note:** You can create you composer.json with your required packages but i just created a simple **composer.json** file with monolog/monolog package. For your understanding you can follow my steps (this). You can remove the package monolog later on.

**Now navigate to the project directory where `composer.json` file located**
Run the following command:

```
composer require phpcasperjs/phpcasperjs
```

And you faced the above problem because of wrong or mismatched version of the intended package. Keep in mind that you always can create composer.json with your custom packages and their versions and which will be your package manager. For more detail about composer please visit [Link](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md)

Comment: That seems to have worked, but can't say I understand why.

Comment: Its because i think the version in your composer file was not the stable version and neither the latest. You had to set version properly if you was doing that manually. Please see package management with composer.